# StartActivity not working when Toast called before it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-toast

When I don't call a Toast before starting another activity, things work as expected. But the activity won't start if I call a Toast before startActivity. Please check this code to understand my problem:

```
class LoginTask extends HttpAsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = (LoginResponse) getMappedModel(result, LoginResponse.class);
            if(loginResponse.getResult().equals("success")) {
                /*startActivity works only if I comment this line*/ Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Logged in Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong username or password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `getBaseContext()` with `LoginActivity.this` and try again.

Comment: Done that. That doesn't help!

Comment: Are getting any error log?

Comment: Try : "This" or "ActivityName.this " . If it is "Activity" , "getActivity()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all your code, I would suggest using getApplicationContext, this will return the context for the application.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext (), "Logged in Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext (), MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your Toast prevents MainActivity from starting, but you should be able to fix it by moving your toast showing code inside `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`. You could also add special intent boolean extra, `showsuccesstoast` which would indiceateinside MainActivity.onCreate that toast should be shown.